# JS fetch request never completes but 200 returned

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have some code which checks if we get a 200 response to fetching a pdf file before trying to embed it in a object tag. E.g.:

```
fetch(this.props.url).then(response => response.status).then(
 data => {
   if (data !== 200) {
 // do some error handling
   }
 }
)
```

We are getting a 200 response back so the error handling doesn't kick in as expected, but what we find is in chrome's networks tab filtering by is:running these requests haven't completed.

[network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3guF.png)

So after a few pages we run out of pending allowed connections and everything gets stuck pending until the page is refreshed.

I've tried a few things like adding headers specifying applicaiton/pdf but I can't get chrome think it has finished downloading the file.

Any ideas? Or a better way to check that we're not going to get an http error message before embedding?

Comment: You should parse the response to JSON first. Look at this example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `fetch` definitely **does not** fulfill its promise until the request is complete. If you're seeing fulfillments occur while you still have pending requests, the fulfillments are not from those requests, they're from other ones.

Comment: @ridoansaleh - There's nothing indicating that the OP is using JSON (indeed, it sounds like they're fetching a PDF), and you don't need to read the response **body** just to check the status code from the header as they are above. (In fact, you need to check the status code -- directly, or via `ok` -- before reading the body so you know what to read.)

Comment: *"I have some code which checks if we get a 200 response to fetching a pdf file before trying to embed it in a object tag."* With the code in the question, you can't access the PDF data, because you throw away everything from the response other than its `status` property in the first `then` handler...?

Comment: How big are your PDFs/how long does it take to download them? `Any ideas? Or a better way to check that we're not going to get an http error message before embedding?` I don't know how you serve the files, but if supported by your backend, you could do a [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) request instead of GET.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, status is being returned as OK, the docs are ~50k or less